# Is it possible to resubmit info for for app which is already submitted to apple review?

Tags: ios, submit, review

I have to submit app for apple review but my concern is once we submit the app along with relative information to be posted in the app store (description, etc), is it easy to resubmit this info later if any changes required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, I have found useful information on apple's own web pages. And it states that there are field marked with (*) can be updated at any moment but other than that we cannot modify any other fields.

**Some Fields which can be updated**

- License Agreement
- Description
- Support URL
- Marketing URL
- Copyright 
  ... and more

**Some Fields which cannot be updated**

- Screenshots
- Keywords
- App Preview
- Icons
- App review info
  and more others.

We can find more detailed information on following links

- [In-App Purchase Configuration Guide for iTunes Connect](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/WorkingWithYourProductsMetadata.html)
- [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html)
- [iTunes Connect Developer Guide Detailed](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppMetadata.html)